# Start activity in service when app is terminated android

Tags: android, xamarin, service, xamarin.android

I'm wondering if I can start an activity when my app is terminated. In OnCreate event I'starting my service

```
StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(SampleService)));

 [Service(Exported = true)]
public class SampleService : Service
{
    CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        myService = this;
        var t = new Java.Lang.Thread(() => {
                _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await ExecutePost(_cts.Token);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }                        

                }, _cts.Token);
            }
        );
        t.Start();
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
```

Method ExecutePost is starting a new activity:

```
public async Task ExecutePost(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(3000);
                    Intent temp = new Intent();
                    temp.SetClass(myService, typeof(MainActivity));
                    temp.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
                    temp.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
                    temp.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    myService.StartActivity(temp);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

        }, token);
    }
```

When app is running the behavior is good - each 3 seconds new activity starts, when app is running in the background - service is also running well.

My question is - is it possible to run this service in the background? If it is - what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: simply start activity onPause?

Comment: I'd like to run an activity e.g @ 4pm every day, so this solution won't work